# Apply logical NOT to propEq and filter in ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm feeling my way though functional programming with [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) and I'm struggling on something sounds like it should be easy.

I want all the entries in an array where a property **does not** equal a value.

For example in pure js

```
const filtered = source.filter(entry => entry.name !== 'something');
```

In Ramda there is a `propEq` so I can easily get all the elements that do match a value such as

```
const filtered = R.filter(R.propEq('name','something'),source);
```

But I can't see how to **do** the inverse of that, to only return values that **do not** equal a value.

I'm sure this must be very easy but I'm struggling to see a built in function to do it, the closest I can come up with is:

```
const others = R.filter(rate => rate.name !== name,res.rates);
```

But I'm sure there must be a better way?

Comment: I know this is an old question but you could actually create a `propNotEq` function by combining `propEq` with `not` like this: `const propNotEq = R.curry(R.pipe(R.propEq, R.not))` ;)

Comment: or even more simple: `const propNotEq = R.complement(R.propEq)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, Ramda has a reverse of `filter` called [`reject`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#reject):

```
R.reject(R.propEq('name', 'something'))(source)
```

You can see this on the **[Ramda REPL](http://goo.gl/RoLX9X)**

Comment: fantastic thanks, I was sure there was a simple way of doing it :)